# create custom ISO in Ubuntu Server 21.04 for unattended and offline installation

Tags: server, system-installation, iso, isolinux

I need to create a .ISO with the cloud-init folder inside that would hold the autoinstall-user-data and meta-data files and edit the grub file to use it

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hirsute
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.04"
```

in the base .ISO for this release there isn´t (I don`t know if for a good reason?), the isolinux folder and files so if I follow the tipical procedure at the end I can´t create  custom .ISO with genisoimage or similar software as I will be missing all that important part in isolinux, for example the isolinux/txt.cfg referenced in all the manuals for ubuntu server 20.4 to do this task.

any ideas on how to create custom .ISOs for this latest release that will use the autoinstall-user-data for an unattended installation in a server ?

Regards

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 21.

Comment: thanks for the remark. I edited the title for 21.04. in any case version was clearly stated in the body

Answer (score 0):

One of the `subiquity` developers published a project to customize the live-server ISO.

- [announcement discourse thread](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/a-tool-to-modify-live-server-isos/22195)
- [mwhudson project home page](https://github.com/mwhudson/livefs-editor)

Before that, a community member had also created a project to customize the installer ISO specifically to embed autoinstall files.

- [covertsh project home page](https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator)

I have not tried either of these solutions myself.

Comment: great compilation of links, thanks. unfortunately those may work for ubuntu 20.04 but newer version 21.04 does not have isolinux folder in the .ISO and procedures are based on changes in files in there, and to recreate the .ISO so those scripts may work in in previous versions but not in the 21.04

Answer (score 0):

What I did was copy the isolinux directory from the Ubuntu 20 server ISO image, make my updates, and create my custom ISO image.   It works for me, but I was wondering if there is a reason why the isolinux directory was missing, and if there is another preferred method for creating custom Ubuntu images on an Ubuntu version greater than 20.

Comment: Thanks for posting what worked for you here! I'm not sure if you're hoping for a reply to your follow-up speculation, but if you are, I suggest asking a new question (or you may find some existing material that is up to date - we do have many posts about this but I've had trouble finding recent ones).